# Spreading multiple props with the same property in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Given two props objects:

```
const p1 = {
  id: "p1"
  //...
}

const p2 = {
  id: "p2"
  //...
}
```

If spreading them both on the same component, like:

```
<MyComponent {...p1} {...p2}/>
```

How React is to determine what property value `id` to use?

May also consider other cases like

```
<MyComponent {...p1} id={"p3"} {...p2}/>
<MyComponent id={"p3"} {...p1} {...p2}/>
```

Basically, whats the rule behind to tell which property value is the value it uses?

Comment: In increasing level of preference it goes from left to right (or from top to bottom if you split each onto a new line), with subsequent ones overriding all previous ones with the same key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the order they appear, left to right. It'll walk through the first spread, assigning props, then through the second, overwriting any duplicates.

Demonstration:

```
const Printout = (props: { x: number; y: number; z: number }) => {
  useEffect(() => console.log(props), [props]);
  return null;
};

const Demo = () => {
  const a = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 };
  const b = { y: 5, x: 6 };
  return <Printout {...a} z={4} {...b} />;
};
```

Console output:

```
{"x": 6, "y": 5, "z": 4}
```

The order that keys are obtained from an object is a different question. See [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/823470) for example.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "first" do you mean left to right?

Comment: Yes, left to right